# Tkinter: resizable text box with scrollable

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, window-resize, tkinter-text

When the following code is run, a text box appear with scrollable. However,  I need to make the textbox resizable with the cursor. How can I it?

```
import tkinter as tk          
import sys

class Redirect():
    def __init__(self, widget, autoscroll=True):
        self.widget = widget
        self.autoscroll = autoscroll
        self.output = widget
              
    def write(self, text):
        self.widget.insert('end', text)
        if self.autoscroll:
            self.widget.see("end")  
        self.output.update_idletasks()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x620+1+1")


frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.place(x=650, y=310, anchor="c", width=850, height=400 ) 

text=tk.Text(frame,width=25, height=8, wrap='word') 
text.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True )

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

text['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
scrollbar['command'] = text.yview

old_stdout = sys.stdout    
sys.stdout = Redirect(text)

root.mainloop()
sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Comment: When you say "need to make the textbox resizable with the cursor" do you mean that you want it to resize when you resize the window as a whole, or do you want to be able to resize just the text widget independent of the window?

Comment: I want to resize just the text widget

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter doesn't directly support this. However, it includes all of the basic building blocks to accomplish this.

All you need to do is add a resize grip that the user can click on, and then bindings to resize the widget when you click and drag that grip.

Here's a simple example. It uses the ttk `Sizegrip` widget. That widget has built-in bindings to resize the window, but we can override them with custom bindings to resize the widget instead. This example requires that you use place, since that's what your original example uses.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ResizableText(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, **kwargs)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.text.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(self.text)
        sizegrip.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
        sizegrip.configure(cursor="sizing")

        sizegrip.bind("<1>", self._resize_start)
        sizegrip.bind("<B1-Motion>", self._resize)

    def _resize_start(self, event):
        self._x = event.x
        self._y = event.y
        return "break"

    def _resize(self, event):
        delta_x = event.x - self._x
        delta_y  = event.y - self._y

        self.place_configure(
            width = self.winfo_width() + delta_x,
            height = self.winfo_height() + delta_y
        )
        return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x620+1+1")

rt = ResizableText(root, width=25, height=8, wrap="word")
rt.place(x=650, y=310, anchor="c", width=850, height=400 )

root.mainloop()
```